# Change sub-menu css class

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I use custom menus with drop down. I want to make two different drop-down menus each with different styling. Wordpress puts drop-down items in a single ul with `class="sub-menu"`. But I need different class for each menu.

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3
  <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
      <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I found that this could be achieve with something called Walker but I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to use a custom menu walker, you can use the classes wp already puts out.

If you add a class to the menu item you know will have a extra `ul`, you'll have something like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="sub-1 menu-item menu-item-3">Item 3
      <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
          <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-2 menu-item menu-item-3">Item 3
      <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
          <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you can then select in your css

```
.sub-1 ul { color: blue; }
.sub-2 ul { color: red; }
```

to add a css class to the menu item, make sure you have "css classes" ticked, in the "screen options" in the menu page.

Comment: It doesn't work. I want to target the UL, not the parent LI. .sub-2 ul {} doesn't work. I don't mind using custom menu walker, I just don't know how.

Comment: hi Ralissa! What doesn't work? here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/q7DJb/

Comment: Thank you! I modified my CSS and everything is fine now :) My code was "ul.sub-2" - that was the problem.